# Clear text in a form from a Button Press in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm new to Kivy. Below is my Kivy code, where I'm trying to clear the form data(TextField) by using a button click event, which is written at the bottom of my kv code.
It gives an error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

**studentregister.kv (See the code from bottom)**

```
MDScreen:
    name: "student_create"
    #StudentRegister:
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "arrow-left"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
                root.manager.current= "newaccount"
        Image:
            source: "images/newstud.png"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .78, "center_y": .9}
            size_hint: .13, .13
        MDLabel:`your text`
            text: 'Create New Student Account'
            #font_name: 'MPoppins'
            font_size: "18sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .84}
            color: rgba(135, 133, 193, 255)
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .7, .07
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .73}
            MDTextField:
                id: "t1"
                hint_text: 'Calling Name'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.43, 'center_y': 0.43}
                background_color: 1,1,1,0
                foreground_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                cursor_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                font_size: '12sp'
                cursor_width: '2sp'
                multiline: False
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .7, .07
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}
            MDTextField:
                id: "t2"
                hint_text: 'Surname'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.43, 'center_y': 0.43}
                background_color: 1,1,1,0
                foreground_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                cursor_color: rgba(0, 0, 59, 255)
                font_size: '12sp'
                cursor_width: '2sp'
                multiline: False                        
        Button:
            text: "Clear"
            size_hint: .35, .065
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .32, "center_y": .06}
            on_release: 
                root.ids.t1.text: ""
                root.ids.t2.text: ""
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: rgba (52, 0, 231, 255)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [5]
```

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from drivermapview import DriversMapView
from mysqlconn import SqlConn
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
Window.size=(310,580)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    connection = None
    cursor = None

    def build(self):
        #Connect to database
        self.cursor = SqlConn.sbdb.cursor()
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        screen_mgr = ScreenManager()
        screen_mgr.add_widget(Builder.load_file("studentregister.kv"))
        screen_mgr.add_widget(Builder.load_file("newaccount.kv"))
        screen_mgr.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))

        return screen_mgr
MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Do not use string ids. Change it like `id: t2` (not `id: "t2"`).

Comment: @ApuCoder Thanks. After changing, the error disappeared. But still nothing happens when clicked the button.

Comment: That's because you used wrong syntax for `root.ids.t1.text: ""` which should be `root.ids.t1.text = ""` or here just `t1.text = ""`.